# create table in postgresql using double quotes

Tags: java, database, postgresql

Whenever we are creating a table, just we are specify as, `CREATE TABLE table_name` in any of the database system. When we are creating a table in postgre then we use,
`CREATE TABLE "tabl_name"`. Is there any difference when we are using the double quotes `" "` for creation of table in postgreSql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are a few differences.

Double quotes tells the parser that what is contained is a case-sensitive identifier, to be read literally.

This leads to a number of differences.  You can do things like:

```
CREATE TABLE "table" ( ... );
```

but not

```
CREATE TABLE table (...);
```

Not only is it case sensitive (PostgreSQL folds unquoted identifiers to lower case) but it can include otherwise forbidden keywords.

This means however that afterwards you must use things like:

```
SELECT * FROM "table"
```

But you can't

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use double quotes round the table name then you are making the name case sensitive. By default tables names (and identifiers in general) that are not quoted are case insensitive.

So for example using the following create statement without quotes:
`CREATE TABLE TestTable...`

means that all of the following can be used to reference the table:
TESTTABLE, testtable, TesTTabLe

whereas if you used quotes in the create statement:
`CREATE TABLE "TestTable"...`

then only "TestTable" can be used to reference this table, the others would not work.

The manual contains a section on exactly this topic that explains it in more detail:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Are you sure about that? (The case-sensitivity "being saved" as part of the table schema, that is.)

Comment: fairly certain. Here is a quote from the postgresql documentation (the link in my answer):

_Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other._

Comment: Right, make *the identifier* case-sensitive .. yet if FOO is case-insensitive then it should match "Foo", which might have been used to create the table, right? (I do not use postgres, mind.)

Comment: No. If you used "Foo" when creating the table `CREATE TABLE "Foo"...`, then FOO (without quotes) will not match the table name - so `SELECT * FROM FOO` would not work.

Comment: @pst: PostgreSQL folds non-quoted identifiers to lower case before doing anything with them so the logic is more like "if not-quoted then ident = lower(ident) else leave-it-alone"; that's applied to the table name in the schema and the identifier in the query before the query tries to look up the table name. So a raw `FOO` will become `foo` before it tries to match `Foo` and nothing useful happens.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference if you only use lower case (contrary to SQL standard which says it should be uppercase).

If you use any uppercase letter without quotes it will be converted to lowercase.

If you use any uppercase letter with quotes it wan't be converted and you'd have to use it all the time to access this table (or column or any other identifier).

The best is to not use quotes in identifiers.